# vue.js select closest element on mouseover

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I created this Element, a menu Band:

```
<template>
  <div class="container-lg">
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
        <li class="nav-item" v-for="link in menuLinks" :key="link.id"><a class="nav-link" :href=link.name @mouseover="moveGif" @mouseout="removeGif"><img :src=link.srcDflt v-if="dflt" class="w-75"/><img :src=link.srcHov v-if="hov" class="w-75"/></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    dflt: true,
    hov: false,
    menuLinks: [
      {id: 1, name: 'random', srcDflt: require('../assets/Dice.png'), srcHov: require('../assets/gifs/Dice.gif')},
      {id: 2, name: 'index', srcDflt: require('../assets/Search.png'), srcHov: require('../assets/gifs/Search.gif')},
      {id: 3, name: 'editorial', srcDflt: require('../assets/Editorial.png'), srcHov: require('../assets/gifs/Editorial.gif')},
      {id: 4, name: 'favourites', srcDflt: require('../assets/Favourites.png'), srcHov: require('../assets/gifs/Favourites.gif')},
      {id: 5, name: 'aboutus', srcDflt: require('../assets/AboutUs.png'), srcHov: require('../assets/gifs/AboutUs.gif')},
      {id: 6, name: 'user', srcDflt: require('../assets/User.png'), srcHov: require('../assets/gifs/UserGif.gif')}
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    moveGif: function() {
      this.dflt = false
      this.hov = true
    },
    removeGif: function() {
      this.dflt = true
      this.hov = false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

It works actually but it change all menu elements on mouse over. So far, so logical. How I have to change the code that each single menu item react to the mouse over? I tryed closest(), but it aint work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be able to try it this way, I roughly understand what you need is this, when the mouse moves over that image then he transforms, that is to say, `srcDflt`, `srcHov`, only one of them exists!

```
<template>
  <div class="container-lg">
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
        <li class="nav-item" v-for="(link,i) in menuLinks" :key="link.id"><a class="nav-link" :href=link.name @mouseover="moveGif(i)" @mouseout="removeGif">
        <img :src=link.srcDflt v-if="index === i" class="w-75"/>
        <img :src=link.srcHov v-else class="w-75"/></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    index:null
    menuLinks: [
      {id: 1, name: 'random', srcDflt: require('../assets/Dice.png'), srcHov: require('../assets/gifs/Dice.gif')},
      {id: 2, name: 'index', srcDflt: require('../assets/Search.png'), srcHov: require('../assets/gifs/Search.gif')},
      {id: 3, name: 'editorial', srcDflt: require('../assets/Editorial.png'), srcHov: require('../assets/gifs/Editorial.gif')},
      {id: 4, name: 'favourites', srcDflt: require('../assets/Favourites.png'), srcHov: require('../assets/gifs/Favourites.gif')},
      {id: 5, name: 'aboutus', srcDflt: require('../assets/AboutUs.png'), srcHov: require('../assets/gifs/AboutUs.gif')},
      {id: 6, name: 'user', srcDflt: require('../assets/User.png'), srcHov: require('../assets/gifs/UserGif.gif')}
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    moveGif: function(i) {
     this.index = i
    },
    removeGif: function() {
     this.index = null
    }
  }
}
</script>
```